# Maximum number of beacons on Google Beacon Platform

Tags: eddystone, google-beacon-platform, proximityapi

Has google set a limit on number of beacons a developer can register on its beacon platform and use Nearby Notifications API? I am planning to do this for my company so just wondering if I could be limited when numbers of beacons grow very large.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no limit to the number of beacons that you can register.

Comment: Thanks! Any references where Google confirms this?